# 5.2.0 version of Apache Meta Model failing with required dependency of org.postgresql.util package

Tags: java, apache-metamodel

I was trying to upgrade the Apache meta model from 4.5.3 to 5.2.0 in my OSGI setup, but it failed since it is looking for org.postgresql.util to be exported by some bundle i.e the 5.2.0 has dependency on org.postgresql.util package.After I provided PostgreSQL driver which exports org.postgresql.util package everything worked fine.

My question is does 5.2.0 version of Apache meta model has strict dependency on org.postgresql.util package?
Does it expects that to be exported as pre-requisite even though I am not using any capability related to PostgreSQL source?
How can I make it work if I don't provide this exported package?

Comment: That does sounds strange. I don't think that's an intended dependency. I'd suggest reporting it on the MetaModel bug tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/METAMODEL